# Can i check if images exists and if they do, can i render them out, else ignore images?

Tags: reactjs, api, select, dropdown

I want to sort my API request. But when I first click the option nothing happens. When I click the other option back still nothing. When I click the other option the second time it starts working.

````
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
//style
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Header from "../components/Header";
//link
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
//redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { loadPreSortB } from "../actions/preSortAction";
//dropdown

const TabakMarken = () => {
  //Fetch
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadPreSortB(sortValue));
  }, [dispatch]);
  //get that data back
  const { brand } = useSelector((state) => state.preSort);
  //dropdown
  const [sortValue, setSortValue] = useState("ASC");
  const handleSortValue = (e) => {
    setSortValue(e.target.value);
    dispatch(loadPreSortB(sortValue));
  };

  return (
    <SortenWrap>
      <Header />
      <SubHead>
        <h2>Marke auswählen.</h2>
        <select defaultValue="{sortValue}" onChange={handleSortValue}>
          <option value="DESC">Alphabetisch A-Z</option>
          <option value="ASC">Alphabetisch Z-A</option>
        </select>
      </SubHead>
...```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.

I recommend you write some missing functions (action creators, reducer and store) to give more info.

Anyway, I encourage you not to mix local state from one component (TabakMarken) with global state from redux. You are dispatching an action based on the state of local state (sortValue). Why dont you delete that state and just write dispatch(loadPreSortB(e.target.value))?
I suggest that because, there is no guarantee that sortValue will have changed by the time that dispatch(sortValue) is called.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dispatching an action based on the state of local state (sortValue). Why dont you delete that state and just write dispatch(loadPreSortB(e.target.value))? I suggest that because, there is no guarantee that sortValue will have changed by the time that dispatch(sortValue) is called.